# Limite de consultas en API de google

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando consultas de distancia utilizando la API de google

```
for r in cursorConsulta:
        googleGeocodeUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='
        punto = str(r[1])+','+str(r[0])
        id = r[2]
        #radioBusqueda = r[3]
        radio = '&radius=4000'
        clave = '&keyword=' + 'anses'
        APIKEY = '&key=' + '****' 
        url = googleGeocodeUrl + punto + radio + clave + APIKEY
        print(url)
        json_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        busqueda = json_response.read().decode('utf-8')
        busquedajson = json.loads(busqueda)
        result =  busquedajson['status']
```

Cuando la api me devuelve el estado

> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Genere una nueva api key para poder procesar nuevamente

```
if result=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
 googleGeocodeUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='
        punto = str(r[1])+','+str(r[0])
        id = r[2]
        #radioBusqueda = r[3]
        radio = '&radius=4000'
        clave = '&keyword=' + 'anses'
        APIKEY = '&key=' + '****' 
        url = googleGeocodeUrl + punto + radio + clave + APIKEY
        print(url)
        json_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        busqueda = json_response.read().decode('utf-8')
        busquedajson = json.loads(busqueda)
```

La pregunta es la siguiente, ingresa a la primer consulta de la api y reprocesa la cantidad permitida, cuando llega a su máximo ingresa en el **if result=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":** y vuelve a procesar, ahora cuando vuelve a generar el mensaje **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** de la segunda API KEY como puedo hacer para que la aplicación se tenga ya que si no sigue ejecutándose con el mensaje de consultas excedidas.

Comment: No creo que generar otra API KEY haga reset de la cantidad de request que ya has hecho, porque si mal no recuerdo eso está asociado al dominio que estas usando. Acá te dejo en enlace de la doc de google al respecto. https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits

Comment: @joalquipe gracias por la respuesta, pero si, hace un reset y puedo volver a procesar otra cantidad de consultas

Comment: ok, disculpa habia entendido que cuando llegado al OVER_QUERY_LIMIT con el primer api key, con el segundo no te funcionaba.

Comment: Puedes mirar qué valor tiene la APIKEY cuando excedes la quota, y según cuál sea generar otra o termnar el programa. También puedes tener un contador global de cuántas veces has excedido la quota.

Comment: @abulafia ya realizo la comprobacion del estado de la api en el if, el problema surge cuando ingresa en el if y consulta esa api key y obtiene el mensaje OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Comment: @Seba79 Lo que quiero decir es que la comprobación sea algo del tipo: `if result=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" and APIKEY=="&key=key1":` entonces haces `APIKEY="&key=key2"`, y si no `if result=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" and APIKEY=="&key=key2":` entonces ya has agotado también tu segunda clave y terminas.

Comment: Podria funcionar voy a implementarlo y te comento, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya hace un tiempo que esta publicación esta realizada, pero realizare esta respuesta con el objetivo de ayudar a quienes ingresen en busca de una respuesta certera.

Mi entorno es Ionic 3, aunque la idea se puede llevar a cualquier entorno.

Tuve el mismo problema con la API de Google utilizando `DistanceMatrixService`, el cual mide la distancia entre dos coordenadas, el problema surgió al realizar una iteración sobre un `Array` en el cual existía una consulta a la API anteriormente mencionada, esto resultaba en un error.

Resolví esto con la utilización de un `timer`, el cual cada cierto periodo de tiempo (diminuto periodo) realiza una consulta a la API de Google y así no exceder el limite de consultas por tiempo.

```
// Code to start the timer
    this.count= 0;
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Buscando los mejores servicios...'
    });
    loading.present();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getDistancias(loading), 40);
```

```
// Function that runs the timer, that is, query Google API
  getDistancias(loading){
    if(this.count>= this.datos.length){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    } else {
      var sucursal = this.datos[this.count];
      this.calcularDistancia(this.posicion, new LatLng(parseFloat(sucursal.position.latitude),parseFloat(sucursal.position.longitude)),sucursal.codigo).then(distancia => {
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(error);
    });
    }
    this.count += 1;
  }
  calcularDistancia(miPosicion, markerPosicion, codigo){
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
      var distance;
      var duration;
      service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [miPosicion, 'salida'],
        destinations: [markerPosicion, 'llegada'],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, function(response, status){
        if (status == 'OK') {
          var originList = response.originAddresses;
          var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
          try{
            if(response != null && response != undefined){
              distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
              duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
              resolve(distance);
            }
          }catch(error){
            console.log("ERROR GOOGLE");
            console.log(status);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Espero que esto sirva de ayuda para quienes buscan una solución a este problema.

Saludos,
Leandro.